# How to enable the button after login as a manager

Tags: c#

For example,  I have a login form and the another form. Some button is disable, because some button is for manager only and I try this code, then I debug it after debugging this message pop-up `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
if (labelLogAs.Text == "Manager")
{
    (this.Owner as MainMenu).buttonInventory.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error, because the operation with `as` operator returned `null`. To avoid this error you need to perform a security check. 
You have two options to perform this `security check`:

Using `as` operator:

```
if (labelLogAs.Text == "Manager")
{
   var owner = this.Owner as MainMenu;
   if(owner !=null)
      owner.buttonInventory.Enabled = true;
}
```

Using `is` operator:

```
if (labelLogAs.Text == "Manager")
{
   if(this.Owner is MainMenu)
      ((MainMenu)this.Owner).buttonInventory.Enabled = true;
}
```

It is his discretion which security check use to avoid this error.

Comment: the code works but the buttonInventory still disable in MainMenu formXD

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", it means that something is null. Please debug it to find what exactly is null. In your case, one of the following expressions is null and you can find it by stepping over the code in the debugger and watching the expressions:

- `labelLogAs`
- `this.Owner as MainMenu`
- `(this.Owner as MainMenu).buttonInventory`

Answer (score 0):

an addition to Ilya Kogan answer. You should do null checks when using the `as` operator like so:

```
var owner = (this.Owner as MainMenu);
if(owner == null)
    return;
```

This is just an example and doesn't necessarily fit your needs.

Comment: Actually I would very rarely write code like this, because it has the potential to cause the worst nightmare called "silent failure".

Comment: As I said, this was merely an example. Of course returning in case of null is not a good practice because of what you stated, nonetheless, you would write code like this for example in event handlers. if you don't want the event to be handled if the source that triggered it is not of a certain type. In that case it would be a "silent failure".

Comment: Agree. (must be 15 characters)